# How can I not secure one cookies in Asp.Net if Web.Config secure all cookies?

Tags: asp.net, security, cookies

If the Web.config has this setting:

`<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" />`

All the cookies are now with Secure and HttpOnly flag, but what if I do need one cookie to be not secured so that I can pass something to the client for its javascript to read the data within it? How can I make this cookie not with Secure and HttpOnly flag?

I need this data to be available for any page, is there a way other than cookie?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the setting in your code take over the setting in Web.Config. Only cookies that have not been specified with Secure and HttpOnly then will be affected by the setting in Web.Config.

The example code:

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("mycookie", "mycookievalue") {
                Secure = false,HttpOnly = false
            });
```

So "mycookie" will not be secured regardless what is the setting in Web.Config